# Prove the existence of a subsequential limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

To prove (partially)

> If the set $\{n\in \mathbb{N}:|s_{n}-t|<\epsilon\}$ is infinite for all $\epsilon > 0$, then there is a subsequence of $s_{n}$ converging to $t$.

the author assumed $\{n\in \mathbb{N}:t-\epsilon <s_{n}<t\}$ is infinite for all $\epsilon >0$, and constructed a subsequence $s_{n_{k}}$ such that

- $t-1<s_{n_{1}}<t\,$,
- $\max\{s_{n_{k-1}},\,t-\frac{1}{k}\}\le s_{n_{k}}<t\quad\text{for}\quad k\ge 2$.

**However, is it really necessary that $s_{n_{k-1}}\le s_{n_{k}}<t\,$?** Aren't $t-\frac{1}{k}\le s_{n_{k}}<t$ enough, by which we can apply Squeeze Lemma?

Comment: It seems you are right provided that $n_{k-1}<n_k$  so that $(n_k)_{k\in \Bbb N}$ is actually a sub-sequence of $\Bbb N.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yeah. The author also said $n_{k-1}<n_{k}$ in its construction process. BTW, he/she explains the rationale behind $s_{n_{k-1}}\le s_{n_{k}}$ is to make sure $s_{n_{k}}$ is monotonically increasing. Hmm... I just don't get it. Not all $s_{n_{k-1}}$ need to be less than $s_{n_{k}}$, I think. Thank you for commenting my thoughts.

Comment: Since $\{m: |s_m-t|<e \}$ is infinite for every $e>0,$ we could just let $n_1=1$ and let $n_{k+1}$ be the least $m>\max \{n_j:  j\leq n\}$ such that $ |s_m-t|<1/k.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet In $m>\max\{n_{j}:j\le n\}$, where did $n$ come from? Probably, typo?

Comment: Typo. It should be $ j\leq k$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I agree with your comments. Thanks.